# Run-time Error 1004; Error handling

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, runtime-error

I've got a problem with my error handling. I'm stitching together a series of numbered files, for multiple business locations. I've written the code to move to the next location loop on the error of "file not there", because each location has a different number of files.

Even with the error handling, I'm getting a Run-time 1004 error. How can this be? It bombs on the second location loop, works on the first. I've used a 15-file loop to be safe, because the max I have encountered is 12.

```
    Sub OpenURL()

    Dim LocBackupFile As String
    Dim CurrentFile As String
    Dim HubFileName As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Filedate = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")

    'Cycle through Hubs
    HubArray = Array("GA100%20-%20AHUB", "TX100%20-%20DHUB", "CA200%20-%20HHUB", "IN100%20-%20IHUB", "WA100%20-%20KHUB", _
            "AB100%20-%20LHUB", "MO100%20-%20MHUB", "NC100%20-%20NHUB", "OH100%20-%20OHUB", "PA100%20-%20SHUB", _
            "IN200%20-%20THUB", "UT100%20-%20UHUB", "ON100%20-%20VHUB", "MN100%20-%20WINO", "NL100%20-%20YHUB")

    For Hub = LBound(HubArray) To UBound(HubArray)

    HubName = Left(HubArray(Hub), 5)
    HubFileName = HubName & " NoLocBackup " & Filedate & ".xlsb"

        For CheckAndOpen = 1 To 15

            LocBackupFile = "http://fastnet.--------.com/sites/fastreports/Hubs/" & HubArray(Hub) & "/locbackup_ws" & CheckAndOpen & ".xls"

            On Error Resume Next
            Workbooks.Open FileName:=LocBackupFile
            On Error GoTo Done

            CurrentFile = "locbackup_ws" & CheckAndOpen & ".xls"
            If CheckAndOpen = 1 Then
                RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                Workbooks.Add.SaveAs FileName:="R:\" & HubFileName, FileFormat:=50
                If RowCount >= 65000 Then
                    DestRowCount = 65001
                End If
                Workbooks(CurrentFile).Sheets(1).Range("A1:H" & RowCount).Copy Destination:=Workbooks(HubFileName).Sheets(1).Range("A1")
            Else
                RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                If RowCount < 64999 Then
                    Workbooks(CurrentFile).Sheets(1).Range("A3:H" & RowCount).Copy Destination:=Workbooks(HubFileName).Sheets(1).Range("A" & DestRowCount)
                Else
                    Workbooks(CurrentFile).Sheets(1).Range("A3:H65000").Copy Destination:=Workbooks(HubFileName).Sheets(1).Range("A" & DestRowCount)
                    DestRowCount = DestRowCount + 64998
                End If
            End If

            Workbooks(CurrentFile).Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next CheckAndOpen

    Done:

    On Error GoTo 0

    Workbooks(HubFileName).Save
    Workbooks(HubFileName).Close

    Next Hub

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? Also is the `HubFileName` workbook actually open when you try to save and close it?

Comment: The line in between the error handling:    Workbooks.OpenFileName:=LocBackupFile

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue (error handling not catching error 1004). 
**This is how i solved it:**
I put the code inside the For loop in a separate "child" sub (i.e. process_file), and passed to it all the required parameters. 
for you: In the "mother" sub OpenURL(), you would have:

```
On Error GoTo err_line 'or do something else
For CheckAndOpen = 1 To 15
   has_err = True
   Call process_file( all required parameters here)
   has_err = False
err_line:
   if has_err then
      'your handling code goes here
   End If
Next
```

and outside the mother sub OpenURL() you would have:

```
Sub process_file(all required parameters here)
  '...code from the for in the mother....
End sub
```

The error handling in the child-sub process_file will still work, but if everything fails the mother will resume.

**Edit**
You may want to use this method to catch only the line that breaks the code (put that line only in a child sub, and do the error handling in the parent). Also, this is a work around, and not an actual fix to the issue.

Comment: That isn't _handling_ errors,  it's _ignoring_ errors

Comment: @chrisneilsen correct remark (ty), i have adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools->Options-> and on the General tab change "Error Trapping" to "Break on Unhandled Errors"

[image]

Comment: Actually, that is already selected. I had the same thought. That's what has me stumped. The error is "handled" in the code.

Comment: Wow - that is freaky then o_0 have you tried using `Err.Clear` after that line to make sure there isn't an existing error interfering from the first loop?

Comment: Also, where in the code do you actually close that workbook before the next loop? It could be a file-access error although ultimately it still shouldn't be prompting